# Будет ли утечки памяти в такой ситауции в Си

Tags: c, утечка-памяти

Будет ли утечки памяти в такой ситауции в Си

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int** array;

int main() {
 array = calloc(1, sizeof(int*));
 array[0] = malloc(sizeof(int));
 *array[0] = 5;
 array = realloc(array, 0);
}
```

Comment: Разве что глобальная :) - в смысле, что нет освобождения до выхода из программы. Но в программе ни один указатель не потерян, так что утечек нет.

Comment: @Harry `array[0]` теряется после `realloc`, по идее.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat А, вы о том, что там 0? Мда, я на это не обратил внимания, о том, что такое можно написать, я и не подумал... Да, в этом смысле вы правы. Но просто писать `realloc(0)` - это вообще обрекать себя на неприятности, ибо сказано: *If new_size is zero, the behavior is implementation defined*...

Comment: Хмм, ладно страдно

Answer (score 1):

Будет. `malloc` есть, а `free` нет. То что указатель потерян не значит что память очищенна

Comment: а если я пишу free то у меня бывает вылетает без причины программа

Comment: Причём когда я проверю дебагером valgrind из linux пишет что нет утечек

Comment: а если в цикле несколько итераций сделать?

Comment: free делается на указателе, а указателя у вас уже нет - потому и вылетает

Comment: realloc очень похож на free.
И в любом случае с циклом всё тоже самое, без утечки показывает дебаггер

Comment: ваш реалок кушает внешний массив, а не внутренний. может gcc как-то оптимизировал эти вызовы